# Deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I am trying to access the node `<accessmode>` in the xml for a specific `<action>`.

```
<controller name="Job">
  <roles>
    <role>1</role>
    <role>3</role>
    <role>4</role>
  </roles>
  <actions>
    <action name="Index">
      <roles>
        <role>1</role>
        <role>4</role>
      </roles>
      <accessmode>1</accessmode>
    </action>
    <action name="Warning">
      <roles>
        <role>1</role>
        <role>3</role>
      </roles>
      <accessmode>3</accessmode>
    </action>
  </actions>
</controller>
```

I tried with the below code.

```
    private string mode;
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "action")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "accessmode")]
    public string Mode
    {
        get { return mode; }
        set { mode = value; }
    }
```

Since the `<accessmode>` is an element under the arrayitem of  I tried so.
But, I am getting the value as null. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of the `XmlArrayItem` attribute is incorrect. It is used on collection properties to specify how the items of the collection are serialized. You should remove this attribute from the `Mode` property, and put this property in a `Action` class that maps to the `<action>` element.